# TCP socket programming

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

> Socket programming to implement a simple client and server that communicate over the network and implement a simple Client Server Communication. The client opens a session with the server on a predefined port and then supplies a line of Text Messages.
>
> The server outputs the Text Message on standard output, and also keeps on running to receive more Text Messages.
>
> When the client closes the session by choosing the Exit option, the connection to the server should be gracefully terminated.
>
> When the server is terminated by pressing control C, the server should also gracefully release the open socket.

I have done this program,but when i input the string and press enter in client side it does not appear in server, but when i input second time the first input appears and the second one is pending.

Second one appears when third input is done...

Can i get a solution for this problem??

```
//Server.c

int main()
{
    int listenfd = 0;
    int confd=0;
    struct sockaddr_in sa;
    char msg[1025];
char c[1];
        int i;

    listenfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(listenfd<0)
    {
        perror("Socket");
        return 1;
    }
    sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sa.sin_port = htons(1234);
    sa.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    while((bind(listenfd,(struct sockaddr*)&sa,sizeof(sa))<0)){return 1;}
    printf("\nBind Successfull");

    listen(listenfd,10);
        while(1){
        confd=accept(listenfd,(struct sockaddr*)NULL,NULL);
        printf("\nConnected");
        memset(msg,0x0,10);
        do{
                read(confd,c,1);
                if(strcmp(c,"n")!=0)
                {
                read(confd,msg,10);
                 printf("\n%s",msg);
                memset(msg,0x0,10);
                }
                else{
                confd=accept(listenfd,(struct sockaddr *)NULL,NULL);
                printf("\nWaiting..");
                //close(confd);

                }

          //  write(confd,msg,10);
        //}
        //msg[rc]='\0'
        }while(1);
        close(confd);
    }
}

//Client.c

int main()
{

    int sock1= 0;
    FILE *serv;
    struct sockaddr_in server,clin;
    char msg[1024],c[1];
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(1234);
    if(inet_pton(AF_INET,"192.168.125.7",&server.sin_addr)<0)
    {
        perror("inet_pton");
        return 1;
    }
    if((sock1 = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0))<0)
    {
        perror("socket");
        return 1;
    }
    if(connect(sock1,(struct sockaddr*)&server,sizeof(server))<0)
    {
        perror("Connect");
        return 1;

    }
        //printf("\nEnter 'y' to exit.");
    while(1){
   // memset(&msg, '0', sizeof(msg));
        printf("\nDo you want to continue(y/n):");
        scanf(" %[^\n]",c);
        if(strcmp(c,"y")==0){
                printf("\nEnter String:");

                scanf("%c",&c);
                scanf(" %[^\n]",msg);
                printf("\nSending String to server..");
                //scanf("%c",&c);
                write(sock1,c,1);
                write(sock1,msg,10);
        }
        if(strcmp(c,"n")==0)
        {
        write(sock1,c,10);
        exit(1);
        }
    }
    close(sock1);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Closely read the man-pages for read()/write() and learn that atleast for sockets those two functions do not necessarily read/write as much bytes as they were told to, but few. So looping around such calls counting until all data or a terminator had been read/written is a good idea, not to say an essential necessity.

Answer (score 0):

Socket programming is not an easy task, especially if you want the code to be non-blocking.
I recommend that you use an existing code rather than writing it from the scratch. You waste a lot of time with reinventing the wheel!

Here you find a threadsafe C++ Socket class in one single *.cpp file with a demo application that shows you hot to send and receive strings in both directions, you can even connect to a Telnet server with the demo application and more...

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34163/A-Universal-TCP-Socket-Class-for-Non-blocking-Serv

This code is approved since years to work without any problem. I use it in a commercial product and can assure you that it is bullet proof.